# Excel formula wouldn't insert from vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in a sheet that is produced from Power query. I need to insert formula from vba into empty column within that table. For some reason the formula would not insert at all. I can Copy-Paste that formula from my vba into the place I want and it will work, but not from the vba procedure.

```
Sub gvFillFormula()
    Range("B3").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(E3/1,mapRange,3,FALSE)"  ' doesn't work!

    Range("B3").Calculate          ' nothing helps
    Application.Calculate
    Range("B3").FormulaR1C1 = Range("B3").FormulaR1C1
    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False    
    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
End Sub
```

It works on a plain sheet, but not on a table extracted by Power query.
Any ideas?

Comment: I've tested it and it worked for me. What type of error do you get? Are you sure you get the formula written in designated cell?

Comment: No error, but no formula in cell B3 either :(  Did you do it on a table generated by Power query ?

Comment: Yes I did it on Power Query table. If you wish you can attach the workbook for our review and assistance (example: https://uploadfiles.io/). Just ensure no sensitive data is included.

Comment: OK, figured out what was the problem. I placed my macro in another sheet (sheet2) and even if I ran it from sheet1 it does place formulas in  sheet2. Stupid me. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do I do it? I am a newbee here.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-does-comment-voting-and-flagging-work

Comment: It looks like my reputation is not high enough to vote.